# Как сортировать json строку по нажатию пунктов меню

Tags: java, android, json, сортировка

Имеется json строка вида:

```
[
    {
        "id":"3",
        "raiting":"4.3",
        "title":"Какое-то название",
        "date":"2017-03-12 22:02:31"
    }, 
    ...
]
```

Получаю данные таким образом:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(Json);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
    int id = object.getInt("id");
    int raiting = object.getInt("raiting");
    String title = object.getString("title");

    ...

}
```

Хотелось бы реализовать меню с тремя пунктами: "Популярное", "Новое", "Все". Т.е. нужно по нажатию этих пунктов сортировать json строку.

Comment: Вам точно json строку нужно сортировать, а не данные json файла? Если дадите json файл, я могу привести вам пример кода на пайтон, как реализовать сортировку по дате, рейтингу и показать "все", что бы это ни значило

Comment: @KitScribe, у меня нет json файла. У меня есть json строка. Ее данные мне нужно отсортировать. Спасибо, но нет, мне не нужен код на питоне, хотелось бы именно под андроид

Comment: Какой, вообще, смысл сортировать строку? Вы хотите отсортировать в алфавитном порядке ключи? Что вы хотите достичь сортировкой? У вас в строке есть **id**, есть **raiting**, есть **title** и **date**. Что тут сортировать? Это всего лишь ключи json файла. Будьте яснее, пожалуйста

Comment: @KitScribe, потому что мне все это надо сделать в одном активити. Мне надо чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Популярное", сортировка происходила по ключу `raiting`. По кнопке "Новое", по ключу `date`. "Все" - по умолчанию. Разобрался с функцией `Collections.sort`. Json строку преобразовываю в `arrayList`, но как сортировать массив несколько раз в одном активити по нажатию кнопки?

Comment: Я понял вас наконец. У вас нет json файла, но есть json строка. Но это не вся строка. Как сортировать? Ну у вас по идее после преобразования должен получиться многомерный массив. Это так?

Comment: @KitScribe, да, все так

Comment: Ну вот и по индексам этого массива и сортируйте данные. Вы же знакомы с индексацией? Ваш массив, по идее, должен иметь следующие индексы: **id** - [0][0], **raiting** - [0][1], **title** - [0][2], **date** - [0][3]

Comment: Как на Java это написать, я, к сожалению, не подскажу. Поэтому и говорил, что могу привести код на пайтон для того, чтобы вы его переписали на Java

Comment: А что мешает перевести строку в модели объектов и дальше уже сортировать список объектов, на пример, в виде `List<>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот код с помощью которого я сортирую json-массив похожий на ваш.

```
//Сортировка JSON массива
        String strJson;
        try {
            strJson=jsondb.loadFromFile(jsondb.getWorkDir().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"phones.json");
            JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;
            JSONObject newJsonObj = null;
            dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
            newJsonObj = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray phones = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("phones");
            JSONArray newphones=new JSONArray();
            int iNumID=0;
            int iMasCount=phones.length();
            for (int j=0; j<iMasCount; j++) {
                int iMaxValue=-1;
                int iNumInAray=-1;
                for (int i=0; i<phones.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject phone = phones.getJSONObject(i);
                    int iNum = phone.getInt("num");
                    if (iNum>iMaxValue) {
                        iMaxValue=iNum;
                        iNumInAray=i;
                    }
                }//for (int i=0; i<iMasCount; i++)
                //Есть кандидат
                JSONObject newJsonObjPhone = new JSONObject();
                newJsonObjPhone.put("id",++iNumID);
                newJsonObjPhone.put("name",phones.getJSONObject(iNumInAray).getString("name"));
                newJsonObjPhone.put("phone",phones.getJSONObject(iNumInAray).getString("phone"));
                newJsonObjPhone.put("num",phones.getJSONObject(iNumInAray).getString("num"));
                newphones.put(newJsonObjPhone);
                //Удаляю кандидата из прошлого массива
                phones = removeJSONArray(phones,iNumInAray);
            }//for (int j=0; j<iMasCount; j++)
            newJsonObj.put("data","dbphones");
            newJsonObj.put("phones",newphones);
            File oldFile = new File(jsondb.getWorkDir().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"phones.json");
            if (oldFile.exists()) oldFile.delete();
            jsondb.saveInFile("phones.json",newJsonObj.toString(4));
            Toast.makeText(this, "Сортировка завершена", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }//try
        catch (JSONException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ошибка Json", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }//catch (JSONException e)
```

Функция removeJSONArray

```
public JSONArray removeJSONArray( JSONArray jarray,int pos) {
    JSONArray Njarray=new JSONArray();
    try{
        for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++){
            if(i!=pos)
                Njarray.put(jarray.get(i));
        }
    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    return Njarray;
}
```

Массив вида

```
{
"data": "dbphones",
"phones": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Абонент1",
        "phone": "910xxxxxxx",
        "num": "223"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Абонент2",
        "phone": "910xxxxxxx",
        "num": "210"
    },
    ...
]
```

}

Сортирую по кол-ву вызовов, вам можно переделать под свои нужды